# is there a way to detect number pad open on mobile devices using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, media-queries

I have a stripe payment form. On mobile devices I want to detect if number pad is open and then there is element fixed to bottom which should appear on top of the number pad.

Is it possible to perform this ?

I tried checking before and after window heights when number pad is open. which doesn't worked well.

Comment: You can use [type="number"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Comment: Nope there's no way to target stripe form elements.